# How to set the destination for file.download() in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

The Google Cloud Storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#download) for `download()` suggests that a destination folder can be specified:

```
file.download({
  destination: '/Users/me/Desktop/file-backup.txt'
}, function(err) {});
```

No matter what value I put in my file is always downloaded to Firebase Cloud Storage at the root level. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848917/node-js-google-cloud-storage-upload-destination-specification) says that the path can't have an initial slash but changing the example to

```
file.download({
  destination: 'Users/me/Desktop/file-backup.txt'
}, function(err) {});
```

doesn't make a difference.

Changing the destination to

```
file.download({
      destination: ".child('Test_Folder')",
    })
```

resulted in an error message:

```
EROFS: read-only file system, open '.child('Test_Folder')'
```

What is the correct syntax for a Cloud Storage `destination` (folder and filename)?

Changing the bucket from `myapp.appspot.com` to `myapp.appspot.com/Test_Folder` resulted in an error message:

```
Cannot parse JSON response
```

Also, the example path appears to specify a location on a personal computer's hard drive. It seems odd to set up a Cloud Storage folder for `Desktop`. Does this imply that there's a way to specify a destination somewhere other than Cloud Storage?

Here's my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Storage_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');

  bucket.upload('./hello_world.ogg')
  .then(function(data) {
    const file = data[0];
    file.download({
    destination: 'Test_Folder/hello_dog.ogg',
  })
    .then(function(data) {
      const contents = data[0];
      console.log("File uploaded.");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Doug, the code is working now:

```
exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Storage_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');

  const options = {
    destination: 'Test_Folder/hello_world.dog'
  };

  bucket.upload('hello_world.ogg', options)
  .then(function(data) {
    const file = data[0];
  });

  return 0;
});
```

The function gets the file `hello_world.ogg` from the `functions` folder of my project, then writes it to `Test_Folder` in my Firebase Cloud Storage, and changes the name of the file to `hello_world.dog`. I copied the download URL and audio file plays perfectly.

Yesterday I thought it seemed odd that writing a file to Cloud Storage was called `download()`, when `upload()` made more sense. :-)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system):

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the /tmp directory, which
>   you can use to store temporary files in a function instance. This is a
>   local disk mount point known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written
>   to the volume is stored in memory. Note that it will consume memory
>   resources provisioned for the function.
>
> The rest of the file system is read-only and accessible to the
>   function.

You should use [`os.tmpdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir) to get the best writable directory for the current runtime.

Comment: Doug, I'm not trying to save my files to the Google Functions Environment, although that might come in handy sometimes. file.download() is a Cloud Storage command, so the default is to download to Cloud Storage, into the root level. My question is how specify a different destination, as the documentation says is possible. I think it's just a syntax issue.

Comment: You must be misunderstanding the API.  download() is for downloading files from Cloud Storage to a local machine.  [upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#upload) is for uploading local content to Cloud Storage.

Comment: I tried changing the bucket from 'myapp.appspot.com' to 'myapp.appspot.com/Test_Folder'. The result was an error message "Cannot parse JSON response at ApiError."

Comment: I think now you're fundamentally misunderstanding how Cloud Storage works.  A bucket name doesn't contain folders or paths.  Any sort of names or paths of a file should be in the file name.

Comment: I just figured out that upload() copied the file from my hard drive to Cloud Storage. download() is doing nothing in my code. I'll keep playing with this...

Comment: Oh, you told me that an hour ago! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the files from Google Cloud Storage to your computer using the following code or command
Install python on your PC
Install GCS on your PC
pip install google-cloud-storage
kesaktopdi.appspot.com
Download .json file and save it in /home/login/ folder
Change your account
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?project=kesaktopdi

```
import os

ACCOUNT_ID='kesaktopdi'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/login/" + ACCOUNT_ID + ".json"
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    #print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(source_blob_name,destination_file_name))

download_blob(ACCOUNT_ID +'.appspot.com',       #account link
              'user.txt',                       #file location on the server
              '/home/login/kesaktopdi.txt')     #file storage on a computer
```

You can also download files from the Google Cloud Storage server to your computer using the following command.

```
                 file location on the server     file storage on a computer
```

`gsutil -m cp -r gs://kesaktopdi.appspot.com/text.txt /home/login`

The program was created by the APIuz team https://t.me/apiuz